# Scalability: Millions of tables vs one big master table and millions of views

Tags: database-design, windows, scalability, postgres, multitenancy

We have to migrate an old (million LOC) system from SAP ADS (formerly Sybase) ISAM based (so called free tables) based system to a PostgreSQL database.

The system implements kind of *multitenancy* regarding putting some basic information (chancellery ID, client ID, fiscal year, etc.) just into the windows folder paths and the SQL statements use these to build table addresses with the appropriate paths for the specific table(-files).

Since SAP decided to shutdown support for the Advantage Database Server, we're forced to migrate the system to another (real) RDBMS.
We pretty much already decided to go with PostgreSQL since that would support kind of namespacing (schemata) to at least map the windows folder paths to something we could use to replicate this.

#### Big things to note

While I am using the term *multitenancy* here, it's not really like this:

1. The tenant sub information spaces share some master data which is maintained continuously.
2. The whole meta data model is bound to a specific software version that is rolled out to our customer's systems
3. We have a lot of varying customer systems in the field (i.e. we kinda lost track of all the use cases served over time)
4. Changes in the factual code are error prone regarding unexpected side effects
5. All in all it's we have a [Big Ball of Mud](http://www.laputan.org/mud/), which doesn't leave us much space for refactoring due to overzealous efforts, but still needs features applied continuously, be it for legal requirements (tax laws changing etc.), or customer (product management) demands.

Thus the above stated things should make it clear that we

- don't want to refactor the database in a way it hits the existing factual applications
- should take a path for the database design that works well for all of our customers system installations (from the single Windows Laptop installation, up to the Corporate Windows file server system)

#### The major ways to Rome

ATM we're discussing two major approaches how to do this:

1. Migrating the existing ADS tables to PostgreSQL table objects as they appear in each of the folders to table instances residing in specific PostgresSQL `SCHEMA` instances.
2. Migrating the existing ADS tables to PostgreSQL *master-table* objects, and create views for them a including a mapping table and a reference key included with the master table and another table where these `SCHEMA` names are mapped using a unique ID.

Both of the approaches are already technically almost solved, and we're able to migrate the existing systems either way.

Though there are still points to consider which path we should take.

- Some of our architects say from their guts that having billions of rows in a single master-table would likely have a significant performance impact with the SQL statements.
- Others (like me) argue that a view/master-table model would have several benefits regarding the overall DB-design efficiency.

We're doing measurements already, but I'd like to hear some advice, maybe some experiences, or even other choices of DB-design ideas, for which of the approaches might scale better.

#### Some edge data:

- The overall system currently maintains ~1000 basic table structures (some of them with +400 column fields).
- We have customers with *multitenancy* paths up to 10.000.
- Some of those (master-)tables might need to keep up rows in the range of billions.
- Since indexes are (seemingly) cheap in ADS, there are sometimes many of these used with the existing ISAM tables.

#### What we already noticed:

- The apprehended performance impact for SQL statements applied to *master tables* through views vs single table objects is way from linear scaling going with the amount of data rows (I've been measuring that using exemplary `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` server side).
- Using tables per `SCHEMA` the `pg_catalog` tends to grow big, especially the `pg_catalog.pg_attributes` table. Any operations done with these (including the PostgreSQL query optimizer) might be hit by the sheer big data content.
- Currently we use a single tablespace for all of the tables. While we could organize tablespaces for each *virtual directory path*, this seems to overcomplicate the DB-design though and might even turn up other problems.
- As mentioned before, single tablespaces for such amount of relations doesn't seem to scale well with PostgreSQL and an underlying NTFS windows filesystem.
- Regarding the underlying NTFS system, we should consider that there will be a minimum block size reserved for each file created, and PostgreSQL creates several files for any `pg_class` *relation* object, which includes tables, indexes, blob fields, etc.

May be what I've offered with my observations here is a bit biased, but I'd like to ask about either alternatives, or absolute no goes for either of those models we're discussing.

---

<sub>Since my boss is a wise guy, and he knows that I am one of the architects supporting the view-model, he gave as a homework to me, to give them information what are the cons actually.</sub>

Comment: wow, sounds hard. You know there is a channel specifically for DB questions? you might get better answers on there.

Comment: @Evan I considered to post that at the [Database Administrators/](https://dba.stackexchange.com) channel, but its about the overall design. Though tightly bound to PostgreSQL implementation.

Comment: And of course, it is hard. Otherwise I wouldn't have come up with that question.

Answer (score 3):

Ok heres my vague architectual advice.

I think you are correct in equating the folders to indexes on a single table rather than schemas.

But accessing a single table through views can occasionally be problematic. I would always advise just modifying the SQL statement rather than running your SQL on a view.

Secondly, the shear volume of data could also be a problem. You may find you have to split it up somehow to remain performant.

I would suggest splitting it by creating more than one database with the same schema and splitting the data by tenant and/or date.

This has the advantage of being able to move the data to physically different hardware if required. The disadvantage of course is that you wont be able to query across the splits as effectively.

Comment: _"But accessing a single table through views can occasionally be problematic. I would always advise just modifying the SQL statement rather than running your SQL on a view."_ Why? The PostgreSQL optimizer promises to flatten these out anyways?

Comment: you might be ok in your case. I've had issues with unions in particular. Also its easier to pass in say a tenant id than to dynamicaly generate named views

Comment: _"just modifying the SQL statement rather than running your SQL on a view."_ That's one of the very crucial parts of the challenge. We don't want to do that in 1st place, but apply transparent transformations as much as possible in 1st place.

Comment: yes I can understand you have some extra challenges over and above simply creating a schema that works. I can only give vague advice from my experience of multi-tenant dbs. ive tried schemas, views, dbs and a big single db in the past on mysql and mssql. multiple dbs seems to work the best.

Comment: _"multiple dbs seems to work the best"_ because we need to  support ing cross joins. It's not a really disjunct _multitenant_ model, just something similar. I appreciate your input thouh.

Comment: sorry I cant be more helpful.

Comment: Regarding splitting the data: Postgres supports [table partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/ddl-partitioning.html) for improving performance while keeping most capabilities of a single table.

Comment: @Marco I am aware about that feature, that's considered as a further optimization in case tit becomes necessary.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, my feeling is too, that splitting to multiple databases would be best. What I got up to now: You have multiple disjunct(?) "tenants" but some shared data. What is not clear to me: Do you need to cross join one tenant just to the shared data or multiple tenants amongst each other? If first, is it an option to replicate the shared data to different databases? If second, can you partition the tenants that need to cross join (and replicate the shared data)? Would it be possible/feasible to move inter-tenant joining out of the database to some "service" that uses both tenant databases?

Answer (score 2):

Make real tables. Then you can actually enforce foreign key constraints, you can actually have indexes that apply only to the subset of entities that actually use them, you can cut waaaay down on contention under concurrent use. You can actually enjoy the benefits of a RDMS...

**Unless** there is some clear and independent tenancy where you can shard the data in such a way that you can keep the single db small (a few gig) for a single tenant *and* your usage patterns are such that the few gigs of data has a few useful indexes along with relatively few writes.

Comment: _Real tables_ have some disadvantages as (at least partly) mentioned: 1. Updates are harder to maintain per `SCHEMA` 2. NTFS is more stressed unless using table spaces for each `SCHEMA` 3. `pg_catalog.pg_attributes` is stressed with a load of redundant, unnecessary information.

Comment: No, sorry. If you have to update your schema, you’d _much_ rather have the change isolated to a single table than the one that **everyone** uses. It cuts down on fragmentation, index rebuilds...

Comment: _"that you can keep the single db small (a few gig) for a single tenant"_ Notice that the system isn't really like this, we don't have absolutely isolated and encapsulated tenants, they all share some master data (which is also continuously maintained).

Comment: _"No, sorry. If you have to update your schema, you’d much rather have the change isolated to a single table than the one that everyone uses."_ That's bound to the versions of our client software we're rolling out. ATM that's done at runtime, if a program enters a specific _"tenant"_ (sorry to abuse that term, it's not really one). So if we install a specific software version at a customers system, we already know that the table structures can be updated for the whole system.

Comment: Also I can't see how _views_ would deny to use foreign key constraints in future vs. _real tables_. The only difference is another key field mapping the view to a _virtual folder_, all other FK references would simply include that mandatory field, so what?

Comment: Yegods, and your customers have to wait for your GodTable to update all of its stuff before anything works? Except every FK check happens on _every_ write because they all live in the same table.

Comment: I've edited my question a bit to clarify the situation. _"Yegods, and your customers have to wait for your GodTable to update all of its stuff"_ How does `ALTER TABLE` statements performance decay regarding the actual contents/quantity of tuples in the table? If you have resilient measures regarding that, this would be helpful input.

Comment: _"Yegods"_ Yes :D. I know that systems design is already fecked from the bones, but well, we don't have any choice to do a serious refactoring of milion lines of Delphi code to leverage the situation :-P. All we can do is simulate what the ADS DB system did as much as possible. There are already hacky (but efficient) implementations of factual features based on simply copying/zipping these ISAM table files around.

Comment: Not to mention that besides the ISAM files, there's are also other plain file data that needs to stay in sync at the corresponding file paths.

Comment: I well know how to design a RDBMS from scratch meanwhile (+30 years of exprience), but to migrate an existing _"Database"_ to another underlying service smoothly is a different challenge. If you have some constructive input I am eager to soak it :3

Comment: Something that concerns me is how transactional activity will impact the system when all data is in a master table with billions of records.  Updating indexes would be a bottleneck, even if you tune your queries to retrieve data quickly.  Partitioned tables will help here.